# Desktop.browse() opens multiple windows

Tags: java, internet-explorer-8, applet, awt, windows-7-x64

We have the following code running in an applet running in JRE 1.6.0_26.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("www.google.com")
```

On some Windows 7 64-bit, IE8 machines this command opens two windows but not on others which should be the same setup.
Does anyone have any idea what would cause this?

Comment: That is not even a compilable statement.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW  Applet also has [`AppletContext.showDocument(URL,target)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#showDocument%28java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String%29).  If the user has a Plug-In 2 JRE, you might also look to deploy it using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) & use the `BasicService` method to display a new page.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect this was just some coding carelessness (which I'm as guilty of as anyone else).

Consider the following code:

```
JButton myButton1 = new JButton("Click 1");
myButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("www.google.com"));
    }
});

JButton myButton2 = new JButton("Click 2");
myButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("www.google.com"));
    }
});
```

Notice the bug here?

The intention was to assign one action to each button, but because of a careless copy/paste after the definition of myButton2, we mistakenly assign a second action to myButton1.

What will happen now is when the user clicks on myButton1, the first action will be invoked resulting in the display of a browser with www.google.com showing, and then the second action will be invoked resulting in either another tab in that window or a whole other window (depending on your browser setup).